# A more complete recursive descent c interpreter

Tags: c, interpreter

I've seen several implementations of recursive descent c interpreters which all seem
to do a pretty good job - yet they all only implement a small portion of the C language -
for example they don't support structs or typedefs etc -

Does anyone know of any code that supports a large portion of the C language.
I know adding more functionality would be pretty trivial - but I'm a bit strapped
for time.

Comment: C interpreter? You mean parser? Or?

Comment: Couldn't you just add a backend to gcc to capture what you need? Hard to find a more complete language parser than a compiler for the language...

Comment: the project is self contained - essentially a c interpreter running on fibers- so size is a 'big' issue

Comment: Unless you thought about adding these things from the beginning, you might have some redesigning in front of you. Adding the *parsing* of these things is easy, adding the semantic rules on the other hand might not be so easy unless the compiler and interpreter was designed with these things in mind.

Comment: What do you need it for? If it's for, say, static analysis, verification, etc., then this project is the best starting point: https://code.google.com/p/c-semantics/ . If you're looking for a small implementation of C-like language, with a tiny memory footprint, then better take a look at http://bellard.org/tcc/ - no interpreter can be smaller than this compiler.

Comment: I'm developing a websocket server with an internal scripting language - the server will run several hundred scripts at once.

Comment: @AshodApakian, are scripts coming over network, and you need a minimal warming-up latency? If so, an interpreter might be a good idea, but choosing a C-like semantics is certainly far from an optimal approach. In any other case (like, if you have the scripts ready and can pre-compile them in advance), choosing interpretation over compilation cannot be justified.

Answer (score 3):

[Picoc](http://code.google.com/p/picoc/wiki/Adding_native_C_library_functions) supports more that most of the Tiny/Small C interpreters.  You might give it a look.  And it does support structures.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use it, [this one](http://www.softintegration.com/) looks awfully good for the job.  There was a Dr. Dobb's article on it [a while back ... there it is](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/ch-a-cc-interpreter-for-script-computing/184402054)